# subfigure floats to last page

Tags: subfloats, includegraphics

Currently I made a figure in LaTeX including eight graphs (the subfigures). The figure has the size of one page which is perfect. The problem however is that the figure is placed on the last page of my file and not on the page that I want it to be.

I used the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]

\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{Brazil.png}

  \caption{Bovespa index}

  \label{fig:sfig1}

\end{subfigure}%

\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}

  \centering

  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{Russia.png}

  \caption{MOEX index}

  \label{fig:sfig2}

\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}

  \centering

  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{India.png}

  \caption{Sensex index}

  \label{fig:sfig2}

\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}

  \centering

  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{China.png}

  \caption{SSE index}

  \label{fig:sfig2}

\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}

  \centering

  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{US.png}

  \caption{AEX index}

  \label{fig:sfig2}

\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}

  \centering

  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{Japan.png}

  \caption{ASX index}

  \label{fig:sfig2}

\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}

  \centering

  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{Netherlands.png}

  \caption{SP500 index}

  \label{fig:sfig2}

\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}

  \centering

  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{Australia.png}

  \caption{Nikkei index}

  \label{fig:sfig2}

\end{subfigure}

\caption{Historical closing prices for all markets}

\label{fig:fig}

\end{figure}

\newpage
```

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `\begin{figure}[h]` with `\begin{figure}[p]` ?

Comment: Yes I tried all those variants but unfortunately nothing seems to work

Comment: [h] makes the end of document quite likely as you are preventing most places from being used. Otherwise unless you provide an example it is hard to to give any specific reason why your float is not positioned, you can use \clearpage to stop it floating further

Answer (score 2):

You not provide an MWE (Minimal Working Example), which we can test as it is. Due to the lack of the MWE, we can only guess about the content of your document.

Your code fragment anticipates that each image should be in own line (row). Is this desired? I rather would organize images in two column and five rows:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes} 
\usepackage[round]{natbib} 
\usepackage{apalike} 
    \graphicspath{ {figures/} } 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb} 
\usepackage{subfiles} 
\usepackage{placeins} 
\usepackage{eurosym} 
%\usepackage[figuresonly,nolists,nomarkers]{endfloat} 
\usepackage{fullpage} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htp]  % <---
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
 \includegraphics{Brazil.png}
  \caption{Bovespa index}
  \label{fig:sfig1}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
  \includegraphics{Russia.png}
  \caption{MOEX index}
  \label{fig:sfig2}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
  \includegraphics{India.png}
  \caption{Sensex index}
  \label{fig:sfig2}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
  \includegraphics{China.png}
  \caption{SSE index}
  \label{fig:sfig2}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
  \includegraphics{US.png}
  \caption{AEX index}
  \label{fig:sfig2}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
  \includegraphics{Japan.png}
  \caption{ASX index}
  \label{fig:sfig2}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{Netherlands.png}
  \caption{SP500 index}
  \label{fig:sfig2}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{Australia.png}
  \caption{Nikkei index}
  \label{fig:sfig2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Historical closing prices for all markets}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note, as you can observe in above MWE, I have removed almost all empty lines (which  push images after images, and preserve it only after each images pair.

**Edit:**
Now, when you provide some information about your document, become clear, that in it you request by use of package `endfloat` that images had to be on the end of document (see @ Axel Sommerfeldt comment below). If you not like to have them on the end, remove this package from your document preamble. Also for image placement instead `[ht]` you should use `[htp]` figure placement option.

**Edit 2:**
I extend my MWE with your document preamble and add some dummy text which show, that provided solution works as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I use this code, the figure is still placed on the last page of my document.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\usepackage{apalike}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage[figuresonly,nolists,nomarkers]{endfloat}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}

Comment: Those are the packages that I used. Can it be the case that something there causes the problem?

Comment: @Ang This is easy for you to test. Just add your packages to Zarko's preamble and compile. However, as long as you do not ddisclose what you do in the text part (use dummy text), it is not possible to help you. For example, you loads multicol, which indicates you set the text in two or more columns. This may push the graphic page to the end, unless you switch column off at at the page where the graphics should be placed.

Comment: @Ang, please edit your question and add those information there. Also extend your MWE so, that it will reproduce your problem. In my test image is at least on the next page where is inserted.

Comment: @Ang Since you use the `endfloat` package the outcome seems to be correct, i.e. the figure will be placed at the end of the document. (If you don't want this behavior, you should not use the `endfloat` package.)

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt, this become clear now after OP provide some information about her/his document..

Comment: When I remove end float the figures are still placed at the end of my document..

Comment: @Ang, sorx, I haven't crystal ball that I would be able to see in your document. In my tests, using dummy test i cant reproduce your problem. And you still not provide an MWE, which reproduce your problem. Please edit your question and extend your code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your problem. See edited answer, where I add some dummy text and show, that image is on the next page where is inserted and not on the end document.